# How can i copy rows from a DataFrame in every 10 rows?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Say i have 974 lines of data. What i am trying to do is to create a new np.array from a dataframe in the following format:

Add first 10 lines to an np.array until the end of dataframe only if the length is 10. Here how i have solved this:

```
clen = len(df)
X = []
for i in range(clen):
    if len(df[i:i+10]) == 10:
        X.append(np.array(df[i:i+10]).astype(float))
```

I believe there is a better way to do that but don't want to do something wrong and couldn't find it.

Also what i want to do is to add every 11th line to another np.array(). That i couldn't find yet.

So i have 974 rows. Beginning from first row, every 10 rows will be added to X array and the next one will be added to another array. Btw, X will be something like this:

```
[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
....]
```

and y will be

```
[10,11,12....]
```

I hope i could explain what i need

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] with some actual sample/fake dataframes that accurately convey your problem. English descriptions and pseudocode are imprecise and ambiguous.

Comment: `X` is a *list* not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select every 11th row, I think the following should work:

```
#starting criteria can be changed if required
indices = list(range(0,len(df),11))
every_eleventh = df.iloc[indices]
```

In general, you can use .iloc if you would like to select based on indexes rather than names.

Comment: Thanks but how can i get X?

Comment: i have applied your approach to X aswell but this time last a few rows are less than 10 elements

Comment: To be honest, I'm a little confused on the initial question. Dataframes are analogous to relational databases - you will always have the same number of columns in every row of a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
list(df[i:i+10] for i in range(len(df)-9))
```

to get X.

And according to your question: `every 10 rows will be added to X array and the next one will be added to another array` use:

```
df[10:]
```

to get Y. But I don't think this is the Y you really desired.